# is packagist.org intended only for libraries, rather than complete applications?

Tags: php, packagist

If I have a complete application, and I want to make it very easy to install, is it appropriate to publish it as a package on packagist.org? Or is packagist intended only for the dependencies you use for putting together other applications?

The objective is to make the most of Composer to make installation easy.

Comment: Applications like [October CMS](https://packagist.org/packages/october/cms) are published on packagist, so why not?

Comment: I don't know what you're referring to with "complete application", but it's common to publish, for example, cli programs on these package repositories. If you look at the JS ecosystem, basically every tool is on npm.

Comment: what I mean is, well, I am writing a PHP web application for managing and scheduling court interpreters and I am going to want to share it. it will depend on a pile of stuff, mostly ZendFramework 3 components. I wonder if it's possible (being somewhat new to Composer, git, github) to make it so all they have to do is say 'composer require my-application', step through some prompts to configure things (I'll write the script), and be nearly, if not completely, ready to go (they will still have to install and configure the rest of the stack).  Looks like the answer is yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from https://packagist.org/about :

> Packagist is the default Composer package repository. It lets you find
>   packages and lets Composer know where to get the code from. **You can
>   use Composer to manage your project** or libraries' dependencies...

So it should be perfectly fine to use it like you want.